# Horizontal spacing of math operator and parenthesis

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, formatting, math-operators, brackets

Take the following code for example,

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \exp x
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \exp (x)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \exp \big(x\big)
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The produced results look like this:

[image]

The first and second results are expected. `\mathop` somehow detects what's coming after to adjust the horizontal spacing: there is spacing between `exp` and `x` while no spacing between `exp` and `(`

But the third one introduces an unwanted spacing between the operator and parenthesis due to using `\big`. How can I eliminate such spacing? Indeed I can do

```
\exp \!\big(x\big)
```

but don't want to change it in every equations in my manuscript...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

never use `\big` in a document that's the internal shared code between `\bigl` and `\bigr` (which you should use here)

You should be able to globally change your manuscript to change every `\big(` to `\bigl(` and `\big)` to `\bigr)`

Comment: I did not know there exist `\bigl` and `\bigr`, thanks!